# Does excludedUserAgents support wildcards?

Tags: experience-analytics

Sitecore docs says:

> You can create a list to assign custom user agents and IP addresses to exclude in the Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config file. You can manually edit this list by adding the user agents that you want to block under the  node and IP addresses under the  node.

More at: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/configure-robot-detection-functionality.html#UUID-5fd30313-8795-95cc-fe93-63bb53496d88_N1559896157868_body

But I can't find any information if some kind of wildcard can be used in `excludedUserAgents` node.

I mean, can I use something like this:

```
<excludedUserAgents>
*Googlebot*
</excludedUserAgents>
```

instead of this:

```
<excludedUserAgents>
Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+Android+6.0.1;+Nexus+5X+Build/MMB29P)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/80.0.3987.92+Mobile+Safari/537.36+(compatible;+Googlebot/2.1;++http://www.google.com/bot.html)
</excludedUserAgents>
```

Asking because I have quite a long list of user agents to exclude and most of them contains "crawler" as a substring.

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: @ChrisAuer Sitecore 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is below. I uses a .Contains() against a List. It has to be an exact match.

```
if (args.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent == null || !AnalyticsSettings.Robots.ExcludeList.ContainsUserAgent(args.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent))
```

Then it is just a simple list Contains

```
public bool ContainsUserAgent(string userAgent)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) userAgent, nameof (userAgent));
  return this.userAgents.Contains(userAgent);
}
```

You can override the CheckUserAgent processor in the excludeRobots pipeline and role you own logic for partial.

```
        <excludeRobots>
            <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.ExcludeRobots.CheckUserAgent, Sitecore.Analytics" />
        </excludeRobots>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that pipeline. Answering my question: no, there is no way to define wildcards for "excludedUserAgents". By decompiling `Sitecore.Analytics.dll` I found that `ContainsUserAgent` method of `Sitecore.Analytics.Configuration.ExcludeList` is used. And this method verifies if the whole user agent string is defined in "excludedUserAgents"

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but my module does this. It has also been added as a feature request for future releases of Sitecore. https://github.com/jasonmaclean/exclude-robot-by-agent